# Autohotkey. Hold two buttons and tap another to increase volume

Tags: autohotkey

I got stuck building an ahk shortcut script to increase / decrease Volume. The idea was to hold down LAlt+LShift and tap F12 to increase one step per tap.
The order in which LAlt and LShift are pressed shouldn't matter.

I came up with this so far:

```
!+::
    While (GetKeyState("LShift","P")) and (GetKeyState("LAlt","P"))
    {
        F12::Send {Volume_Up}
    }
Return
```

But somehow it increases the volume on holding LAlt and taping F12. LShift gets igronred..

What's wrong with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
    F12::Send {Volume_Up}
```

isn't a command, it's a hotkey assignment. You cannot use it within executable context. It is actually the short form for:

```
F12::
send {volume_up}
return
```

You wouldn't wanna have a `return` somewhere in between the lines which should be executed, would you.

As can be read in the documentation, you can only combine **two** Hotkeys for an action easily, like `a & b::msgbox, you pressed a and b`. E.g. for <kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>b</kbd> AND <kbd>c</kbd>, you'd need some workaround like the crossed out, old answer below.

BUT you can add as many modifiers to your hotkey as you want. Modifiers are `!` <kbd>alt</kbd>, `+` <kbd>shift</kbd>, `#` <kbd>win</kbd> and so on (please have a look @ http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols).

So you can simply use

```
<!+F12::send {volume_up}
```

-

<s>So, your aim is simply to have `volume_up` be fired when *three* Hotkeys are being pressed. You can achieve it like this:</s>

```
#if getKeyState("LShift", "P")
    *<!F12::send {volume_up}
#if
```

or

```
*<!F12::
    if(getKeyState("LShift","P"))
        send {volume_up}
return
```

For the meaning of `*` and `<` and other possible modifiers, see http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

---

Your approach wasn't too bad. It would have worked if you had used the [Hotkey](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) command instead of an actual hotkey assignment. Still that would have been unneeded work

Comment: Thanks for your helpful information! Is there a way to set your last method in a way that the order in which Alt and Shift are pressed doesn't matter?

Comment: Jesus. Why is there so little activity for AHK on Stackoverflow. If some more people had read my post, it would have gotten 5 downvotes, because it was just bullsh*t. I updated my answer, the whole thing is way easier

Comment: Haha, that simple! Works fine. I came up with the complicated approach in the first place, so I guess the bullsh*t is on me :-) Thanks for your help!