# AutoHotKey if statement not working

Tags: if-statement, syntax, autohotkey

What is wrong with this?

```
if A_OSVersion = WIN_7 or A_OSVersion = WIN_XP
   {
   MsgBox, Win7 or XP
} else {
   if WinActive("ahk_exe Explorer") {
   !f::!h
   }
}
```

The goal is to replace Alt+F with Alt+H in Explorer when I'm running Windows 8, 8.1, or 10, and I am testing on a Windows 7 machine, so the code shouldn't run at all, but the hotkey does and the `MsgBox` doesn't. Do I need to reorder things for it to work? The syntax looks right to me, but I've been having a hard time with syntax for AHKscript.

Kind comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
!f::!h
```

isn't a command, it's a key remap and thus, implicitly contains a `return`. You cannot use it within executable context. For details, see http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remarks somewhere below.

You wouldn't wanna have a return somewhere in between the lines which should be executed, would you.

(this was mostly a copy of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314898/autohotkey-hold-two-buttons-and-tap-another-to-increase-volume/33317281#33317281))

---

For [context-sensitive](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context) hotkeys, use the preprocessor directives:

```
#if (A_OSVersion = "WIN_7" or A_OSVersion = "WIN_XP") and not winActive("ahk_exe Explorer")
   !f::!h
#if
```

Comment: Sweet! All I needed to do was put the `not` on the other part of the `if` and change `Explorer` to `Explorer.exe` and it worked like Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
#if winActive("ahk_exe Explorer") and !(A_OSVersion = "WIN_7" or A_OSVersion = "WIN_XP")
  !f::!h
#if
```

To do it within normal script flow you will need to used the Hotkey Command but then it will not be a remap but a hotkey that sends another set of keys...