# AutoHotKey - How do I use a key combination on an IF statement?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to disable Alt + F4 but I want to enable it when I press Windows Key + Q. So far I've got this which isn't working.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

if (#q)
{
    Send !{F4}
    Return
} else {
    !F4::Return
}
```

Comment: @Blauhirn, I don't really know much about AHK. Can you give an example as to how it's cleaner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ; autoexecute section:
 Alt_F4_enabled:= false
 ; ...
     return   ; end of autoexecute section

#q:: Alt_F4_enabled:= true

!F4::
If Alt_F4_enabled
{
    Send !{F4}
    Alt_F4_enabled:= false
}
else
    return   ; do nothing
return
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what does the `; ...` on the 3rd line do?

Comment: Also, your code works just partly. While it does disable Alt + F4, pressing Win + Q doesn't do Alt + F4, but after pressing Win + Q, I can press Alt + F4 manually and it works again without being blocked.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work by moving `Send !{F4}` up to `#q` and closing that off with `Return`.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning `#q` and `!F4::Return`: These are **no** commansd, they're hotkeys and thus, implicitly contains a `return`. You cannot use it within executable context. For details, see http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remarks somewhere below.

You wouldn't wanna have a return somewhere in between the lines which should be executed, would you.

(also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509166/3779853))

For toggling hotkey actions, I prefer using the `Hotkey` **command** ([link](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm)):

```
hotkey, !F4, closeWindow, ON ; this is a command. "creates" a hotkey

closeWindow:  ; this is a label
    send !{f4}
return

#q:: ; this is a hotkey
    hotkey, !F4, closeWindow, TOGGLE ; this is a command. disables or enables the hotkey
return
```

doing so, it's easy to dynamically give `!F4` even more functions.

code not tested

but in fact, there's no big reason why you couldn't do it user12344312257994344s way.